# HTTP-requests caching in SailsJS?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Using SailsJS I'm building backend for an app and have to withstand a lot of identical requests.

Requests are processed by Sails controllers endpoints, which fetchs and processes some data from DB, and sends JSON formatted results in responses.

Same requests produces the same responses, until rare changes in DB has been made.

To reduce DB queries times I can tune DB engine caching (it's MariaDB in my case).

But is there any way to cache frequent requests on the serverside completely to exclude DB queries and consequent data processing?

Can existing node.js caching modules, like [node-cache](https://github.com/mpneuried/nodecache), be used with Sails?

Comment: Please clarify whether you are talking about requests that produce same response like css js files ?

Comment: Same requests produces same responses. In some definite period of time, at least. But responses are neither static assets, nor SailsJS views. It's some JSON data, generated by Sails controllers.

Comment: If you want to save database hits cost use a cache in between. Am i understanding your problem correctly ?

Comment: By the way the standard on SO is that you explain your problem in detail and more importantly tell the community what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to details. Updated question.

Answer (score 3):

Your architecture is starving for a cache. You should use [redis](http://redis.io) or [memcache](https://memcached.org/). Whenever a request occurs and data is fetched from db you insert it in redis and send the response to the client. When the next time such a request occurs, your server will first look into redis and if it finds the data there it will return the response it got from redis, rather than querying it from your database (we call it cache-hit). If incase the data doesn't reside in redis, you will query your database but there is a catch here. The catch is that you will not directly return the response to the client, but, first put it in cache and then return the response (this is called cache-miss). Redis and memcache etc. are in-memory stores. The cost to fetch data from cache is much lesser than fetching from a database. There are further discussions on this topic, but they will throw us out of scope.

Good luck. Hope it helps. Try and let us know.